# How to avoid AndoridManifest overriding with maven

Tags: android, maven, android-manifest, apk, android-maven-plugin

I have a project almost equals to the [android-quickstart archetype](http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes):

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=android-quickstart \
-DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes \
-DarchetypeVersion=1.0.11 \
-DgroupId=your.company \
-DartifactId=my-android-application
```

I added an aar dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.41-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

And configured the android-maven-plugin to merge the manifest:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mergeManifests>true</mergeManifests>
            </configuration>
            <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Then I do `mvn clean install`.

I thought that this was going to merge the two manifests and put the result straight into the apk (in `my-app/target/my-app.apk/AndroidManifest.xml`). But instead it is overriding my original AndroidManifest.xml (in `my-app/AndroidManifest.xml`).

Is there any way to leave the original AndroidManifest.xml intact (like Gradle does in Android Studio)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Since `android-maven-plugin` 4.1.0, this is the default behavior, and additional configuration is not needed.

Add these lines to your `configuration`:

```
<androidManifestFile>${project.build.directory}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
<sourceManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</sourceManifestFile>
<updatedManifestFile>${project.build.directory}/AndroidManifest.xml</updatedManifestFile>
```

This should copy your original manifest first, then update the copied file.

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project my-app: Manifests were not merged! -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project my-app: Manifests were not merged!

Comment: This works with no merged manifest for sure (i use this config in my project), but just for a single updated manifest.
Is this the only relevant part of the error log?

Comment: Sorry, the relevant part is:
Error: [my-app\target\AndroidManifest.xml] XML file not found
Error: [my-app\target\AndroidManifest.xml] Failed to read manifest file.
[ERROR] Manifests were not merged!

Comment: It seems the manifest was not copied. Are you using the latest android-maven-plugin? It is clear you are not, because it now has a [new groupid](http://www.simpligility.com/2014/11/android-maven-plugin-4-0-0-ships/). Be ware that this version has breaking changes, so maybe you could update to `3.9.0-rc.3` for now with the old groupId.

Comment: Great! This is documented [here](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/generate-sources-mojo.html#sourceManifestFile). (This page is referenced in the README in GitHub).

Comment: `android-maven-plugin` 4.1.0 is released, which uses the wanted behavior by default, no configuration is needed!